# DOCTYPE html messes my css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using materialize framework and as I add `<!DOCTYPE html>` it does not recognize my CSS. But it works without `<!DOCTYPE html>`. How should I solve this error?

**Update :**

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Material</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
        <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function(){
                $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            body{background-color:#fcfcfc;}

            .logo{
                height:70%;
                margin-top:10px;
                margin-left:10px;
            }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
                .logo{          
                    margin-left:0px;
                }
            }
            .button-collapse{
                margin-left:5px;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
            <div class="navbar-fixed">
                <nav class="blue lighten-1">
                    <div class="nav-wrapper">
                      <a href="index.php" class="brand-logo"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" /></a>
                      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                        <li><a href="index.php" class="waves-effect waves-light">Home</a></li>                          
                        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">Signup</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">Contact Us</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                        <li><a href="index.php" class="waves-effect waves-light">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">Signup</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-light">Contact Us</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
            </div>

    <div class="row header-img">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it break all CSS or only for some of the tags?

Comment: where do put your css ? in external or internal?

Comment: can you show the CSS?

Comment: That's because your CSS relies on quirks mode. That's bad.

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: why is there php code in there? does the css work if you remove that?

Comment: No it does not. The php code is there because I am gonna use php for getting the data from database.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that browsers switch to a more correct rendering engine mode when they see a doctype in the file.

If adding a doctype is causing problems, then your code has probably something wrong with it, and it is working by chance (or trial and error) if nothing else. There is a slight chance that the culprit might be a bug introduced in the more standards-compliant rendering mode, though. Such bugs do exist.

Without the doctype your page will be renderd in quirks mode. That means that the browser will treat your html AND your css after the rules the older browsers have set.
Valid html MUST have a doctype. If you have a correct and fairly new doctype then your document will be rendered in Standards Compliant mode. Also, your stylesheets must have a media type of text/css.

I think sharing your CSS here might help in identifying what exactly is going wrong.